# Как в VK SDK работать с приватностью?

Tags: vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Использую Android VK SDK в своем приложении. Есть необходимость изменять приватность для пользователя. То есть нужно, чтобы приложение могло управлять настройками, разрешая писать в диалоги определенным группам или только друзьям.

В документации нашел только описание самого объекта: https://vk.com/dev/objects/privacy

Но непонятно, каким методом этот объект отправлять? С помощью каких методов API можно получать и устанавливать настройки приватности?

Comment: В какие именно диалоги ? в чат или иное(уточнить) ?

Comment: @Alex Допустим, между двумя пользователями.

Comment: при помощи api Вы можете создавать чат, добавлять в него участников и удалять их из него - Вы это имеете ввиду?

Comment: Нет. Нужно, чтобы пользователь мог запретить вступать с ним в диалог определенным категориям людей (например тем, кого нет а друзьях). Т.е., чтобы пользователь мог изменять настройки приватности.

Comment: можете удалять вопрос, это сделать в настоящее время нельзя.

Comment: @Alex а откуда такая уверенность? Опять-таки зачем в документации приведено описание объекта который за это отвечает?

Comment: приватность можно устанавливать не на все объекты, например можно поставить приватность на фото (об этом написано в api). А уверенность потому, что на всякий случай был сделан запрос в саппорт API VK  - *метода управляющего приватностью пользователя в открытом доступе нет*.

Comment: я не проверял, но можно же отснифать запрос с браузера или телефона и подделать запрос, по идее, должно работать. Я такое с музыкой делал

Comment: если sdk не даёт таких возможностей, можете попробовать написать свои rest запросы, но думаю, если вк запрещает, то и через рест тоже работать не будет